# Why does if condition give error in bash?

Tags: windows, bash

My code below:

```
echo "====================================="
echo "      Test Programme                 "
echo "====================================="
echo 

read -p "Enter Name: " name


if [$name -eq ""]; then
    sleep 1
    echo "Oh Great! You haven't entered name."
    exit
fi

read -p "Enter age:  " age
```

According to that code,I expected `"Oh Great! You haven't entered name."` to show up when user skips entering the name which WORKS WELL

But, when you enter a proper string for name, it gives this message/ error:

`./cool_ham.sh: line 13: [Franco: command not found`

I want to know the reason for that.
I have even tried `"$name" = ""` after @Jack suggested, but still din't work .

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ will catch this, and things like it, automatically.

Comment: This question is in no way specific to `if`. `[$name -eq ""]` would behave the same way if it were *not* inside an `if` condition, and likewise, the correct form -- `[ "$name" = "" ]`, or `test "$name" = ""`, or `[ -z "$name" ]`, or `test -z "$name"`, or `! test -n "$name"` -- will work just as well either inside or outside of `if`.

Comment: BTW, "still din't work" is not the same thing as "same error again". If you get a different error (and you certainly *would* have gotten a different error from Jack's suggestion, even misunderstanding it to no longer include `[ ]`; `Franco: command not found` is not the same error as `[Franco: command not found`), post that actual new error.

Comment: To try to explain the issue in yet another way: In `[ "$name" = "" ]` or `test "$name" = ""`, the `[` or `test` (literally, `/bin/[` and `/bin/test` are often two hardlinks to the same binary, or for shell-builtin implementations two hash table entries for the same function call); but regardless, it's a command named `[` or `test` that's running the comparison for you; it's not part of `if` syntax. You can't run that command unless you name it, and a command name isn't recognized as a command name if it's smushed against anything else without spaces.

Comment: ...so, just as how `ls/tmp` won't work but `ls /tmp` does, you need to run `[ "$foo" ]`, not `[$foo]`, so that the command name -- `[` -- is a separate word. (`]` is a mandatory closing argument to `[` for readability purposes, but inasmuch as that decision confuses people to think that `[ ]` is syntax instead of a regular command, it arguably was a bad one).

Comment: Hey Charles, I tell you what -z $name works perfect among the other options that your told

Answer (score 0):

Put a space between the square braces of your `if` condition and its contents.

```
if [ "$name" = "" ]; then
```

Additionally note that I use `=` over `-eq` to compare strings. `-eq` is used to compare integer values, while `=` will compare strings, which can be unintuitive coming from other languages.

I also quoted $name to [prevent globbing and word splitting](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).

Comment: Doesn't work Jack, its givin me another error- integer expression expected :)

Comment: -eq is for integer comparisons, to check string equality simply use $name = "". I'll edit.

Comment: Also note that he quoted `$name`. This is important in some shells when `$name` is empty, and it's just good practice.

Comment: Oh no, its giving me the same error again . I had accepeted the answer last time w/o checking cuz i was on the mobile app :) Sorry

Comment: @Tilak, `[ "$name" = "" ]`, or `test "$name" = ""` -- the `[` or `test` (literally, `/bin/[` and `/bin/test` are often two hardlinks to the same binary, or for shell-builtin implementations the same function call), but regardless, it's a command named `[` or `test` that's running the comparison for you; it's not part of `if` syntax.